# Communicate to NXT over USB from C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nxt, lego-mindstorms

Are there any good tools to connect to a LEGO Mindstorms NXT from a PC in C++? I've tried NXT++ (https://github.com/cmwslw/nxt-plus-plus), but it was decidedly ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

NXT++ is a good library, but it wasn't working for me. I ended up writing code from scratch to interface with WinUSB. That technique can work, when I have it more cleaned up maybe I will post it.